# Debugging assembly unloadability in .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windbg

I have an assembly which I need to unload dynamically.  I have followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability for both the development of my loader as well as the debugging using WinDbg.  I have a "memory leak" because my unload command is not working.  My question is how do I make my unload work?

Initially, I noticed that memory was not going down after using the unload command, so I created a dictionary of weak references which point at the assemblies.  I dynamically load and unload the assembly every time I perform an operation, which is creating multiple copies of the assembly in memory.  I can use the Dictionary<int, WeakReference> to see if the assemblies have been unloaded or not as they do in the guide above.  They aren't getting released, no matter how long I wait, or how many times the garbage gets collected.  This says to me that there's some outstanding reference, but for the life of me I can't find it.

I'm not making either of the mistakes they made in the example code- the only reference I hold onto is the weak reference.  I even assign the assembly and the assembly loader to null once I'm done with them, though they go out of scope immediately anyway.  I don't have any callbacks or, to the best of my knowledge Types across the border because the only communication I do across the boundary is via a file.  The assembly is ending appropriately without issues.  So I fired up WinDbg and tried to follow their instructions.  Everything goes fine until I try to get the GC roots of the AssemblyLoader:

```
0:000> !gcroot -all 0x00007ff7b943f9c8
Found 0 roots.
```

And when I step through the threads in my application, I don't see anything that jumps out to me as suspicious, though honestly I don't have enough intuition in this area that that means much.  The output is below.

```
0:021> ~*e !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x3510 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000FEA5D7E6E0 00007ff8813111c4 [InlinedCallFrame: 000000fea5d7e6e0] Interop+User32.WaitMessage()
000000FEA5D7E6E0 00007ff7b8f38a15 [InlinedCallFrame: 000000fea5d7e6e0] Interop+User32.WaitMessage()
000000FEA5D7E6B0 00007ff7b8f38a15 ILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke()
000000FEA5D7E770 00007ff813db015e System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr, msoloop, Void*) [/_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Application.ComponentManager.cs @ 398]
000000FEA5D7E860 00007ff813db28f5 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) [/_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Application.ThreadContext.cs @ 1111]
000000FEA5D7E8F0 00007ff813db2568 System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) [/_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Application.ThreadContext.cs @ 975]
000000FEA5D7E950 00007ff813a89c86 System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form) [/_/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Application.cs @ 1198]
000000FEA5D7E990 00007ff7b8bd9f4a ConfigTool.Program.Main() [C:\Users\isherman\Documents\Projects\twmp\FormsConfigTool\Program.cs @ 42]
<snipping out unmanaged threads>
OS Thread Id: 0xa2dc (6)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000FEA667FC30 00007ff88338d8c4 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000fea667fc30] 
OS Thread Id: 0xc5fc (7)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
<snip>
OS Thread Id: 0x900c (12)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
<snip>
OS Thread Id: 0x9b88 (16)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
<snip>
OS Thread Id: 0xa358 (18)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
OS Thread Id: 0x9a8c (19)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
<snip>
```

And here's the code that I use to execute and unload the Assembly Load Context:

```
        private static Dictionary<int, WeakReference> references;
        private static int refCount =0;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static int ExecuteAndUnload(string assemblyPath, 
                           XmlDocument doc, out WeakReference alcWeakRef)
        {
            references ??= new Dictionary<int, WeakReference>();
            assemblyPath = Path.GetFullPath(assemblyPath);
            var alc = new SequesteredTagBrowser(assemblyPath);
            Assembly a = alc.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            Debug.Assert(a.EntryPoint !=null);
            alcWeakRef = new WeakReference(alc, true);
            references.Add(refCount++, alcWeakRef);
            //I pass some xml in as an argument to the Program.Main function
            var args = new object[] {new[] {doc.OuterXml}};
            a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, args);
            a = null;

            alc.Unload();
            alc = null;
            GC.Collect();

            return 0;
        }
```

And here's the code for the SequesteredTagBrowser class:

```
    public class SequesteredTagBrowser:AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

        public SequesteredTagBrowser(string mainAssemblyToLoadPath) : base(isCollectible: true)
        {
            
            _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(mainAssemblyToLoadPath);
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName name)
        {
            string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(name);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Since you tagged this with Winforms and i assume you want to show a form from the loaded Assembly i could speculate that that is the problem. When showing a form those gets registered in the Application class of Winforms. When the hole Winforms subsystem isn't only part of your LoadContext  but part of the hosting process as your stack suggest then the subsystem presumably still has cross LoadContext References.

Comment: That makes some sense... Is there a way to unregister the forms?  Or is all I can do refactor the code in some way without using the form?

Comment: @Ralf if you would like to make an answer to that effect, I'll accept it- all I had to do was make sure the form was getting garbage collected in the other assembly before it returned, rather than relying on it automatically happening.